# Understanding qperf's output

Tags: linux

I am using qperf to measure latency between two servers (running linux) connected through a network of switches. Following is a sample output. I am confused interpreting the results.

```
% qperf -vvt my_server tcp_lat
tcp_lat:
    latency          =  15.7 us
    loc_cpus_used    =  66.5 % cpus
    loc_cpus_user    =  25.5 % cpus
    loc_cpus_intr    =    14 % cpus
    loc_cpus_kernel  =  23.5 % cpus
    loc_cpus_iowait  =   3.5 % cpus
    loc_real_time    =     2 sec
    loc_cpu_time     =  1.33 sec
    rem_cpus_used    =    27 % cpus
    rem_cpus_user    =     4 % cpus
    rem_cpus_intr    =    11 % cpus
    rem_cpus_kernel  =    12 % cpus
    rem_real_time    =     2 sec
    rem_cpu_time     =   540 ms
```

How does *_cpu_time fit into the latency? The latency is 15.7us, however the loc_cpu_time is 2s and the rem_cpu_time is 540 ms. Are these the time contributed by the CPUs to the latency or what does this indicate?

I am trying to measure the latency through my system and also have a profile of how much is CPU time and how much is the network time. Is qperf 
the right tool? Any other linux based tool?

Thanks